# Blank Cell Until Data is Entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope somebody can help. I have attached a screenshot of my problem. I have created a gannt sheet for my father-in-law's business. As you can see the dates continue past the entries I have made. I want those cells to be blank until I enter data. Grateful for any help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add an "IF(" formula in front of the formula you have in the finish date cell.  It'll look like this.  Let's pretend the Site Set Up Start Date (12/10/2015) is in Cell D3.

If(D3="","",____).  Where there's the blank, paste in the formula you currently have in that cell and you'll be good.  It'll only display a date in the Finish Date column if there's data in the Start Date Column.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, the formula currently in cell D7 (site set up date) is: =WORKDAY(D7,C7,nonworking) it is gathering data from another sheet to work out non work days, so are you suggesting the formula should now be: 
if(d7="","",=WORKDAY(D7,C7,nonworking))

Comment: Almost; the equals introduces the formula and shouldn't be present as an introduction except as the first character. `=IF(D7="","",WORKDAY(D7,C7,nonworking))`